# VisualBasicAddImportCodeFixProvider encountered an error and has been disabled

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

[image]

This appears at the top of my code window in Visual Studio 2015.

Is it likely that I did something to cause this? I was working with Linq in a Data Repository class if that helps.
Am I OK to just enable it and move forward?

I see the issue was logged on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4395

Comment: There is no point in reporting this bug at SO.  VS2015 Update 1 is coming soon, it has a *lot* of Roslyn fixes.  Currently available as RC if you can't wait.

Comment: Are you suggesting I didn't do anything wrong and that there's no risk to clicking enable?

Comment: This wouldn't be caused by any of your code executing. This is an error that happened in an extension or some other piece of code that is a part of Visual Studio. The provider is there to insert "Imports xxx" statements in your source code or fully qualify types to make a code error go away. I believe that you could enable it as it shouldn't irreparably scramble your source code (help is just an undo away).